# Trying to use contains selector within nested divs

Tags: jquery, contains

```
<div>
    <div>test</div>
</div>

$("div:contains('test')").css('display','none');
```

I know I am going to kick myself on this.  The problem is that when this runs all divs are hidden due to nesting. How do I make it so that the parent div does not get hidden?   I am limited to using  1.2.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("div:contains('test'):not(:has(div))").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an elegant solution, define a new selector. Unfortunately, `:empty` is not sufficient as anything with text node children isn't empty.

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  leaf: function(elem, i, match) {
    return $(elem).children().length == 0;
  }
});
```

And then you can do:

```
$("div:leaf:contains('test')").hide();
```